# ARCore tap position on augmented image

Tags: java, android, arcore

I'm making an app with Android Studio + Java + ARCore (v 1.13 so no ARFragments, ARsceneViews ecc, but OpenGL instead) that recognizes work arts (such as The kiss by Hayez) and I wanted to add some interaction, in particular when the user taps on the work art (used as an augmented image) i need to get the position (in relative space) of the tap on the augmented image (would be better for it to be from -1 to 1 using the getExtent function).

I tried to "reverse engineer" the example augmented_image example that places objects in relative space (i.e. it places 4 corners around the augmente image) obtaining something like

```
Pose worldHitPose = hit.getHitPose();
Pose anchorPose = ((AugmentedImage) trackable).getCenterPose();
Pose localHitPose = anchorPose.compose(worldHitPose);
```

but the results are highly inconsistent (everytime i restart the app the result are different).

```
Pose worldHitPose = hit.getHitPose();
Pose anchorPose = augmentedImage.getCenterPose();  
Pose localHitPose = anchorPose.compose(worldHitPose);
float x = localHitPose.tx() / augmetedImage.getExtentX();
float y = localHitPose.ty() / augmetedImage.getExtentY();
```

x and y should be -1 > x and y > 1, instead they go from -30 to up to 7.